# how to create file outside public_html in php on shared host

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I am trying to create a file outside of the public_html in php:

`fopen("/home/sites/foo.org/backup-ticketing/asu.sql";w)`

However I am getting this error message. I am sure I should be able to do it somehow I just can't figure it out. Permission of the folder is `711`.

> [Wed Aug 01 14:33:54 2012] [error] [client 84.3.2.16] PHP Warning:
>   fopen(/home/sites/foo.org/backup-ticketing/asu.sql) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:
>   Operation not permitted in
>   /home/sites/foo.org/public_html/back/asu.php on line 4

Could you please advise me what is the right way to do please?

Thank you for the many advices now I have an additional info:

php.ini is the problem in public_html however I would like to keep it as it is but /back/ folder should be able to do so.

here is my settings:

```
 file_uploads = Off
 upload_tmp_dir = /var/php_tmp
 upload_max_filesize = 0M
 allow_url_fopen = Off
 allow_url_include = Off
 safe_mode = Off 
 display_errors = off
 magic_quotes_gpc = off
 magic_quotes_runtime =    off
 max_file_uploads=0 
 disable_functions=passthru,exec,phpinfo
 open_basedir  = /home/sites/foo.org/public_html/
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202818/php-editing-text-file-above-root

Comment: The permissions of the directory are 711, but what is the owner:group of the directory?  What is the user (and any applicable groups) that PHP is being run under?

Comment: sorry not being too detailed, but the php.ini was/is causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It seems as PHP's [`Safe mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) or [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) are enabled preventing you from what you want to do - so it's simply not allowed and therefore not possible.

You could check if you are allowed to write to some other directory outside of your public directory, often `../tmp` or `../temp` are there and writable.

You might be able to find out what paths are allowed by open_basedir with

```
echo ini_get('open_basedir');
```

Another way around your problem: Put your files in a subdirectory of your public directory and secure it with .htaccess (User/Password, deny all IPs but your ow etc.)

EDIT:

- Protect directory with username/password via htacces: Use a [htaccess generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/), or
- Allow access only from certain IPs: Create a file and name it .htaccess with the content below

  `order deny,allow`

  `deny from all`

  `allow from 888.888.888.888`

Comment: I like the htaccess version could you provide some sample please? thx

Comment: the htaccess suggestion is really useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a shell_exec.

there you could exec a script with a different user than the webserver user

http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

After a research I found the obvious answer:
open_basedir  = none
in php.ini
I though someone would find useful.

Thanks for all the answers and I have learned a lot from them.